# Optional extern interface implementation in dll

Tags: c#, dll, interface

I am creating some integration library that is about to accept various implementations of interfaces to make it run.

I have a setup:

library

```
interface IModule {
    void Init();    
}
interface IExample : IModule {
    void DoSomething();    
}
class Core {
   IExample Example {get; private set;}
}
```

Core class is looking for each property of type IModule and for each of this type, based on external configuration assigns an instance object that implements interface of property type.

Then I have a module that meets requirements of Core.

```
class MyExampleModule : IExample {
   public void Init() { }
   public void DoSomething() { }

   public void ExampleFeature1() { }
   public void ExampleFeature2() { }
}
```

I want to close module MyExampleModule in a .dll, and I want it to run in environment w/o Core and it's IExample and IModule interfaces. (I want one .dll, not two for environments w/ and w/o those interfaces).

Is there a way to achieve that in C#? If not (just for curiosity reasons) is there a language in which it's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. The CLR needs the assembly with the interfaces because it needs to know what they look like. However, if you're that concerned about shipping two assemblies (why?) you can merge them with [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx). That brings other problems and considerations with it though. Are you going to merge another module with core too? That will probably cause runtime exceptions.

I'm not aware of another .NET language that can do what you want. And in fact, I doubt there's any other language that support interfaces that aren't shipped with the implementing code.